# mod_rewrite change a variable content

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am having a little trouble with apache mod_rewrite, I need to be able to modify (append) a variable name to something else depending the regex in another variable in the URL:

```
https://localhost:85/fight?shoes=baby.firstlove&type=textype&awesome=23481234
```

By this i mean that if "awesome=" is 234[8,7]1234, shoes=baby.firstlove should become shoes=baby.firstlovefirsttry, OR if awesome=234[1,2]1234, then shoes=baby.firstlove, should become shoes=baby.firstlovesecondtry .

My rewrites rule are something like this (trying to capture awesome=23411234 or awesome=23425678):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} shoes=(.+)\&awesome=(\b234(1|2)\d{4}\b)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:85/fight?shoes=baby.firstloveactual&subscriber=%2 [P]
```

But they are not changing the "shoes=" variable content as expected. 
The URL remains the same:

```
http://localhost:85/fight?shoes=baby.firstlove&type=textype&awesome=23481234
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"not changing the `"shoes="` variable content as expected"* -- What is happening? Please include any relevant output or error messages in your post (click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40219803/edit)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} shoes=(.*)\&awesome=(\b234(1|2)\d{4}\b)
> ```

Your regex does not match your example URL:

> ```
> https://localhost:85/fight?shoes=baby.firstlove&type=textype&awesome=23481234
> ```

You have an `8` where your regex is expecting a `1` or `2`. However, if you need to match one of a series of characters then you should use a character class (eg. `[12]`) rather than a parenthesised/capturing group. Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the word boundaries (ie. `\b`)? What is the intention of using the `P` flag? Presumably you need to *externally redirect*?

But also, your code sample does not seem to match your textual description of the problem?

> if "awesome=" is 234[8,7]1234, shoes=baby.firstlove should become shoes=baby.firstlovefirsttry

Try the following (assuming "1234" is the literal string, rather than *any* 4 digits):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} shoes=.+&awesome=(234[87]1234)
RewriteRule ^/?fight http://localhost:85/fight?shoes=baby.firstloveactual&subscriber=%1 [R,L]
```

You've used `https` in your example URLs, but `http` in your rewrite?

Comment: Sorry lots of errors in my original post. Cleaning up now.

Comment: I think I have found a solution that kind of works:

`
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} shoes=baby\.(\w+)\&(.*)\&awesome=(\b234(1|2)\d{4}\b)

RewriteRule /fight?(.*)$ http://localhost:85/fight?shoes=baby.firstloveactual&%2&awesome=%3 [P]
`
This kind of takes care of the urlse that have a variable between shoes and awesome, such as:

[link]http://localhost:85/fight?shoes=baby.firstlove&type=textype&awesome=23481234

I'll see if it survives the light of day...

Ok I think Ive lost the battle to put code in comments.

Comment: The above (including your original condition) already "takes care of URLs that have a variable between `shoes` and `awesome`", that's what the `.+` does in `shows=.+&awesome` - it matches everything (which might be too much - although that is what your revised regex does as well). Note that in the pattern `/fight?(.*)$` - The `?` makes the preceding "t" optional, and the trailing `(.*)$` is superfluous. Ah, are these rules directly in your server config? I'll update my answer (I assumed you were using `.htaccess`).

Comment: I dont know how to use htaccess files yet. Is it any different?

Comment: I changed the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ from `^fight$` to `^/?fight`. mod_rewrite works a bit differently in per-directory `.htaccess` files (and `<Directory>` containers) than when used directly in the server config. One key difference is the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_.

Comment: Thanks for the insights!